# Оптимизация алгоритма нахождения доминантных простых чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Данный алгоритм позволяет находить доминантные простые числа.

Число **x** является доминантным простым числом, если:

- **x** - простое
- если к числу x добавить любую цифру слева, это число не должно быть простым.

К примеру:
3 не доминантное простое число, так как 13 является простым.

- если числа, входящие в число **x** являются простыми.

К примеру:

7937 доминантное простое, так как 7937, 937, 37 и 7 простые, и  17937, 27937, 37937, 47937, 57937, 67937, 77937, 87937, 97937 не простые числа.

**Проверка выполняется только при добавлении только одной цифры к числу.**

---

```
import math

def test_prime(n):
    k = 2
    maxk = int(math.sqrt(n))
    while k <= maxk:
        if n % k == 0:
            return False
        if k == 2:
            k += 1
        else:
            k += 2
    return (n is not 1)
```

---

```
def dominant_prime_finder(base=None,maxprime=10**12):

    if base == None:
        for digit in range(1,10):
            if test_prime(digit):
                dominant_prime_finder(digit)

    elif base <= maxprime:
        dominant_prime = True

        for i in range(1,10):
            new_base = int(str(i)+str(base))
            if test_prime(new_base):

                dominant_prime = False
                dominant_prime_finder(new_base)


        if dominant_prime == True:
            print('base',base)
```

---

```
from time import time
start = time()
dominant_prime_finder()
finish = time()
print(finish-start)
```

---

Как можно оптимизировать данный алгоритм? Выполнение данного алгоритма занимает примерно 2 минуты, нужно сократить выполнение в два раза. Диапазон выполнения алгоритма до 10^12.

Смотрю в сторону динамического программирования, дабы оптимизировать количество выполненныех операций.

Comment: Один раз посчитать. Сохранить результат в файл. В дальнейшем (в готовой программе) пользоваться готовой таблицей как статическим набором данных. Время работы сократится на порядки.

Comment: `test_prime` это разве стандартная функция? Какая у неё сложность?

Comment: Непонятно - условие "так как 7937, 937, 37 и 7 простые" - насколько обязательно? При *убирании* крайней левой чтоб число оставалось простым - насколько это важно? Если это важно - то доминантных простых очень небольшое количество, проще их посчитать справа налево...

Comment: @pavel Добавил функцию **test_prime**

Comment: @MaksimFedin тогда сразу советую заменить на что-то логарифмическое) А вообще таблицу простых чисел до миллиона Эрастосфеном каким и использовать уже её. Ускорит секунд до 3.

Comment: @Harry не так и мало на самом деле.

Comment: @Akina нужно чтобы результат возвращался за минуту.

Comment: Выборка из готового файла будет занимать время, необходимое на чтение файла - скорее всего, это будут секунды, а то и доли секунды.

Comment: *Добавил функцию test_prime* Опять же - выполнить предрасчёт простых чисел в требуемом диапазоне гораздо быстрее, чем каждый раз устраивать прыготню по две единички с самого начала.

Comment: @Akina извиняюсь, забыл добавить , что диапазон простых чисел до 10^12.

Comment: @MaksimFedin мы видим. Просчитать все простые числа до 10^6 занимает доли секунды. После чего проверка на простоту числа будет занимать не ~500k операций а только 30k